# synchronized method override- thread acquires lock on which object?

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrancy

This question came in my mind from an example of Java Concurrency in Practice. In chapter2 of the book , we get an example like this , I am not copying that completely. Lets say we have following block of code

```
class A{
 synchronized void method1(){
  do some stuff..
  }
}
class B extends A{
  synchronized void method1(){
  super.method1();
  }
}
```

Now  we create an object of class B and do following things, this goes under public static void main.

```
B b=new B()
Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b.method1();
        }
    });
 Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b.method1();
        }
    });
```

And subsequently start the t1 and t2 threads.

**Here my question are**:

1. As I have synchronised method here on which object thread gets lock? I am creating only B object and for B's "method1" I can think of thread acquires the lock on B object , but while executing following code

   super.method1()

And control subsequently reaches super class's method1 on which object it acquires the lock? As I have not created any object of class A.

2. And how this behaviour linked to Reentrancy?

Comment: How about posting code that actually compiles, please? There's nothing in what you show that would allow either thread to invoke `method1`, or indeed use an instance of `B` at all. This in turn obscures your question so that it's unknown what you're asking and impossible to answer.

Comment: apology, corrected.

Comment: Except for the semicolon. Do you actually compile and run the code you post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is only an instance of `B`, that's the object whose monitor will be acquired.

The `super.method1()` call also acquires the monitor (re-entrantly). The object is still `B`, it makes no difference that the method is defined in the superclass since the monitor is still acquired from `this` (i.e. the same exact instance).

Comment: But the posted code shows no indication that either thread accesses any instance of `B`.

Comment: I've learned to disregard the posted code and just extrapolate the information.

Comment: I've learned the opposite. I can't count the number of times in my career I've been shot down for "extrapolating" (guessing) wrong. It's part of software engineering to provide and to demand clear, unambiguous requirements.

Comment: I don't make guesses at work. While it would be nice to also have high quality questions in addition to high quality answers, I doubt that's very easily achievable.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for reply, Apology for typo. quoting this from the same book "Reentrancy is implemented by associating with each lock an acquisition count and an owning thread. When the count is zero, the lock is considered unheld. When a thread acquires a previously unheld lock, the JVM records the owner and sets the acquisition count to one." now that means count  for object B's lock would first becomes 1 when it will execute " b.method1();"

Comment: @Mu.Arg And? In your example code the count would be `2` when inside `A.method1()`.